# My list displays two columns of the same workflow

Tags: 2007, column, designer-workflow

One of the oddest things I've seen on SharePoint to date...

I have a list which was created from a template with a few workflows already attached to it. After I created the list, I deleted all of the workflows and created an entirely separate one in SPD.

Normally, SPD would put in the workflow column so you can see the progress, history log, etc. Well, it actually put two columns in, and if I display one column, the other is displayed as well. In the view settings, it shows two instances of the column. Even if I uncheck one, it will display both.

Is this a common problem? Any easy fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a common problem, but it happens sometimes.

Get [SharePoint Manager 2007](http://spm.codeplex.com/downloads/get/57473) From CodePlex and find the offending column (You may have to put it in full mode I can't remember) and make a note of the GUID.

Then using powershell or a console app do the following:

```
// Not real code, just the process
Using SPWeb
GET SPList
Get SPField.Fields["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
SET SPField.Hidden = FALSE
SET ReadOnlyField = FALSE
SPField.Update
SPList.Fields.Delete(SPField.InternalName)
```